# Find $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \int^{\pi/4}_{0} \alpha e^{x} (\tan x)^{\alpha} dx$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can you help me show that
$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \int^{\pi/4}_{0} \alpha e^{x} (\tan x)^{\alpha} dx=\frac{e^{\pi/4}}{2}$
?

Comment: Hello welcome to math.stackexchange! What have you tried?

Comment: I tried showing that integral as a function of $\alpha$ by using recurrence relation.But it doesn't work

Comment: Use the substitution $t = \tan^{\alpha+1}x$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
This is a *Laplace Method* example:

- The main contribution to the integral comes from $\ds{x \lesssim \pi/4}$.
- Under the change $\ds{x \mapsto \pi/4 - x}$, the main contribution to the integral comes from $\ds{x \gtrsim 0}$.

Namely,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{\alpha \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}
\alpha\expo{x}\tan^{a}\pars{x}\,\dd x} =
\lim_{\alpha \to \infty}\bracks{a\int_{0}^{\pi/4}
\expo{\pi/4 - x}\tan^{a}\pars{{\pi \over 4} - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\expo{\pi/4}\lim_{\alpha \to \infty}\bracks{a\int_{0}^{\pi/4}
\expo{-x}\exp\pars{a\ln\pars{\tan\pars{{\pi \over 4} - x}}}
\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\expo{\pi/4}\lim_{\alpha \to \infty}\bracks{a\int_{0}^{\infty}
\expo{-0}\expo{-2ax}\,\dd x} =
\expo{\pi/4}\lim_{\alpha \to \infty}\pars{a\,{1 \over 2a}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{1 \over 2}\,\expo{\pi/4}} \approx 1.0966 \\ &
\end{align}